# bash docker command not found in centos7 after installing docker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I installed docker in centos7 and started docker service.

I checked docker service it is running. But when I run `docker --version` getting error like `bash docker command not found`. Why?

Comment: Please update your question with examples of how you check that is running and from the error.

Comment: add /usr/local/bin to PATH

Answer (score 0):

Add "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox" into my path environment